# QStyleSheet property for QPushButton with empty text

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qtstylesheets

I'm attempting to do something like this:

```
QPushButton[text=""] {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

QPushButton {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Basically, some of my QPushButtons have text, and some don't, and I want to style the ones that do differently from the ones that do not.

This works if I switch on an actual string value, ie

```
QPushButton[text="Ok"] {
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Then any buttons that say "Ok" have a red background. But what do I pass in for a button with no text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This style sheet works for me (Linux, Qt 5.3):

```
QPushButton[text] {
    background-color: "green";
}

QPushButton[text="some text"] {
    background-color: "red";
}

QPushButton {
    background-color: "blue";
}
```

Comment: Beautiful, works like a charm. It never occurred to me to make the "default" QPushButton style the one for the buttons with no text, and specify a separate style for the buttons with text. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

---

**LAST EDITED** : 9 / 8 / 2014 1:05

OK, I'm sorry for my misunderstood the question.
I have same problem with you to set empty text. But It work in Qt Designer. (Why ? I don't know.) And I can't find other property.

I have solution, I create my property '`isEmpty`' in `QPushButton` by inheritance them. And, add is property, Like this;

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class customQPushButton (QtGui.QPushButton):
    def setPropertyIsStringEmpty (self, text):
        self.setProperty('isEmpty', QtCore.QVariant(False if len(text) > 0 else True))

    def setText (self, text):
        self.setPropertyIsStringEmpty(text)
        QtGui.QPushButton.setText(self, text)

class exampleQMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.testQPushButton = customQPushButton(self)
        self.testQPushButton.setText('')
        self.setStyleSheet ('''
            QPushButton {
                color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            }
            QPushButton[text="Ok"] {
                background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
            }
            QPushButton[isEmpty=true] {
                background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
            }
        ''')
        self.setCentralWidget(self.testQPushButton)
        self.testQPushButton.keyPressEvent = self.keyPressEvent

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
window = exampleQMainWindow()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It's OK from your create new object. But, If create by Qt Designer, I have to refresh Property by call `setPropertyIsStringEmpty (self, text)`.

---

Regards,

---

**MESSAGE BY 9 / 8 / 2014 1:05** : This is my old post. if useless, please avoid them.

> It's possible If you create your `style sheet` pattern and put this
>   `style sheet` in your code or statement to you want setting.
>
> I have example, this example show i handle arrow (not down key only)
>   key press event and set new color of button;
>
> ```
> import sys
> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
>
> ENUM_COLOR_RED   = 0
> ENUM_COLOR_GREEN = 1
> ENUM_COLOR_BLUE  = 2
>
> def getStyleSheetQPushButtonRed ():
>     return '''
>         QPushButton {
>             color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
>             background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
>         }
>     '''
> def getStyleSheetQPushButtonGreen ():
>     return '''
>         QPushButton {
>             color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
>             background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
>         }
>     '''
>
> def getStyleSheetQPushButtonBlue ():
>     return '''
>         QPushButton {
>             color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
>             background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
>         }
>     '''
>
> class exampleQMainWindow (QtGui.QMainWindow):
>     def __init__ (self):
>         super(exampleQMainWindow, self).__init__()
>         self.testQPushButton = QtGui.QPushButton('KM', self)
>         self.setCentralWidget(self.testQPushButton)
>         self.testQPushButton.keyPressEvent = self.keyPressEvent
>
>     def setText (self, text, color):
>         styleSheet = {
>             ENUM_COLOR_RED   : getStyleSheetQPushButtonRed,
>             ENUM_COLOR_GREEN : getStyleSheetQPushButtonGreen,
>             ENUM_COLOR_BLUE  : getStyleSheetQPushButtonBlue
>         } [color]()
>         self.testQPushButton.setText(text)
>         self.testQPushButton.setStyleSheet(styleSheet)
>
>     def keyPressEvent (self, eventQKeyEvent):
>         key = eventQKeyEvent.key()
>         if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Left:
>             self.setText('LEFT', ENUM_COLOR_RED)
>         elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
>             self.setText('UP', ENUM_COLOR_GREEN)
>         elif key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Right:
>             self.setText('RIGHT', ENUM_COLOR_BLUE)
>
> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
> window = exampleQMainWindow()
> window.show()
> sys.exit(app.exec_())
> ```
>
> **Advantages** : you can put color independent text in button.
>
> **Cons** : You color `style sheet` have set anytime when have event by statement.
>
> ---
>
> This is useful for implement Style Sheet, I hope is helps;
>
> **Reference** : http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html
>
> ---
>
> Regards,

Comment: You misunderstood the question -- I know how to set the text of a button and I also know how to set the stylesheet of a button. I'm looking for the correct property in my STYLESHEET to style a button with no text.

Comment: I'm sorry for my misunderstood the question. I have edit my answer. please discuss, thanks.

Comment: This is a good workaround...I was, however, hoping to avoid subclassing QPushButton. Does QPushButton have a property I can use, or am I forced to create my own?

Comment: Ummmm..., I don't see other property in QAbstractButton.cpp, you can see this reference: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/staging/source/4377e247e135967eb7b4c89906415abecb283bd3:src/gui/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp#L869, Thanks.